# How to implement a busy indicator in vscode?

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

For a long running process I'd like to show a busy indicator in Visual Studio Code. It would already be enough to have something like the typescript extension uses:

[image]

However using a normal status bar item doesn't work as expected. I cannot even show the item right before I start the operation, because it seems to require returning control to vscode for that.

What I have tried is this:

```
...
busyIndicator = window.createStatusBarItem(StatusBarAlignment.Left, 1000);
busyIndicator.text = "##";
busyIndicator.show();

...

workspace.onDidSaveTextDocument((doc: TextDocument) => {
    if (doc.languageId === "antlr") {
        //busyIndicator.show();
        busyIndicator.text = "X";
        let tempPath = Utils.createTempFolder();
        let result = backend.generate(doc.fileName, { outputDir: tempPath, listeners: false, visitors: false });
        Utils.deleteFolderRecursive(tempPath);
        //busyIndicator.hide();
        busyIndicator.text = "Y";
    }
});
```

The value X is never shown and Y comes up when the operation is over (as expected). If not even a simple text update works, how can I even show an animation?

Comment: Now see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_show-long-running-operations-as-notifications-with-cancellation-support Not for the status bar but a notification.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I wasn't able to figure out when support for using `withProgress` in the status bar was added, but I can do the following today.

Edit I found when the support for this was added, it was April 2017. See vscode release notes [here](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_12#_new-apis)

```
 vscode.window.withProgress({
    location: vscode.ProgressLocation.Window,
    cancellable: false,
    title: 'Loading customers'
}, async (progress) => {
    
    progress.report({  increment: 0 });

    await Promise.resolve();

    progress.report({ increment: 100 });
});
```

See it in action in the following image

[image: gif]

Answer (score 8):

Now see https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_22#_show-long-running-operations-as-notifications-with-cancellation-support Not for the status bar but a notification.

**

> Show long running operations as notifications with cancellation
>   support

**

> We added a new API to show long running operations in the Notification
>   Center with optional cancellation support. The benefits of showing
>   long running operations here are: Multiple operations can report
>   progress at the same time. You can show operation progress. The user
>   has the option to cancel the operation.
>
> Call `window.withProgress` with the new progress location
>   `ProgressLocation.Notification`. Set cancellable to true to show a
>   cancel button and check for cancellation on the provided
>   `CancellationToken` in the callback. To display progress, leverage the
>   increment value when reporting progress. See the progress sample for
>   an extension using this new API.

Comment: Nice to see this addition, though it won't help in cases like mine, where I have no progress to report. I'd need an indetermined progress indicator. Should create a FR for that...

Answer (score 1):

There is no published API similar to what `Tasks` does (displaying that spinning in StatusBar). But looking at VSCode source code, specifically `task.contributions.ts` you can see it combines `setInterval` and `EventEmitter` to handle the *progress* and *status bar update*.

The [Webpack Progress extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wk-j.webpack-progress) is a good example on how to do this.

Basically, you have to create the interval in which you want your StatusBar to be updated. Here will be your `backend` process monitoring:

```
initializeWacher() {
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
        this.progress++;
        fs.stat(tempPath, (err, state) => {
            if(err && err.code === "ENOENT") {
                this.emit("progressFinish")
            } else {
                this.emit("progressChange", this.percentage)
            }
        });        
    }, 300);
}
```

Handle the events emitted by the interval:

```
watcher.initializeWacher();
watcher.on("progressChange", (progress) => {
    progress.updateProgress(progress);
});
watcher.on("progressFinish", () => {
    progress.finishProgress();
    watcher.dispose();
});
```

And update the StatusBar when the events occurs (the spinning itself):

```
private static progressChars: string = '|/-\\';
...
updateProgress(percentage) {
    ...
    let index = percentage % BusyIndicatorItem.progressChars.length;
    let chars = BusyIndicatorItem.progressChars.charAt(index);
    busyIndicator.text = "Backend processing " + chars;
}

finishProgress() {
    this.statusBarItem.text = "Backend finished";
}
```

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but it brought me on the right track. Essential here is also that the task runs asynchronously or it will block the main thread and hence no updates happen. Once I converted it to return a promise things started to go as expected.